# How to launch a (Rust)Actix-web server as a lib from another thread

Tags: rust, interop, actix-web

I want to launch my simple actix-web server from a c++ console app as a proof of concept.
This is my attempt in the Rust code:

#### lib.rs

```rust
use std::{io};

use actix_web::{get, middleware::Logger, App, HttpServer, Responder};
use actix_web_lab::{respond::Html};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn API_Start_Server() {
    println!("Rust about to launch server.");
    actix_web::rt::spawn(async move {
        // Thread will be consumed until server is closed.
        let _ = start_server();
    });
    println!("Server has been launched, returning.");
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn start_server() -> io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .service(index)
            .wrap(Logger::default())
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .workers(2)
    .run()
    .await
}

#[get("/")]
async fn index() -> impl Responder {
    Html(include_str!("../../Client-Side/index.html").to_string())
}
```

But clearly i am doing something wrong because when i call `API_Start_Server` from my c++ code:

#### ServerLauncher.cpp

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> // Windows API header

// Function signature for initializing and starting the Actix server
typedef void (*StartServerFn)();

int main()
{
    std::wstring wsRelativePath = L"..\\..\\..\\..\\..\..\\..\\target\\release\\actix_server_library.dll";

    // Load the Rust shared library
    HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibrary(wsRelativePath.c_str());

    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading shared library: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get a function pointer to the Actix server's entry point
    StartServerFn startServer = (StartServerFn)GetProcAddress(handle, "API_Start_Server");

    if (!startServer) {
        std::cerr << "Error finding function symbol: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        FreeLibrary(handle);
        return 1;
    }

    try
    {
        // Call the Rust function to start the Actix server on a new thread
        startServer();
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what();
    }

    // Continue with other tasks in the main thread
    // ...

    // Wait for the Actix server to finish (in a real application, you may use proper synchronization)
    std::cout << "Press Enter to exit..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    // Clean up and close the shared library
    FreeLibrary(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

An exception gets thrown and in the console log i can see the following message:

```
Rust about to launch server.
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at '`spawn_local` called from outside of a `task::LocalSet`', src/Server-Side/Rust/lib.rs:10:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I get that im probably not calling the server creation correctly by spawning another thread to do so and I probably need some state to store the server on but i am new to Rust and actix and cannot find any examples of how to do this. How do i create the server from an outside thread and have it live as long as the dll is loaded from the c++ side?

Comment: `actix_web::rt::spawn` can only be called from _inside_ an Actix Web runtime, but you're trying to use it to _start_ the runtime. Instead you should spawn a regular thread with [`std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html).

Comment: Derp, that did indeed solve it. I no longer get an exception thrown. Ill post a proper solution after i play around with it some more and make a proper "CloseServer" function that will class the thread handle. Thank you!